# Unable to configure python to proxy

Tags: python-2.7

None of the earlier posts related to my question below were able to provide me a solution. So i am posting in a new thread.

I connect to the internet thru an authenticated proxy in my university. So in browsers, i give in my username password. However i am unable to download data in python.

i entered the following 4 lines in python 2.7 to download data. i have successfully installed pandas and datetime libraries; so the first 2 lines below have no problems.

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
goog = DataReader("GOOG",  "yahoo", datetime(2000,1,1), datetime(2012,1,1))
print goog["Adj Close"]
```

The error i get is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 3, in  <module>
pass
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py", line 53, in DataReader
return get_data_yahoo(name=name, start=start, end=end)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py", line 134, in get_data_yahoo
lines = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
return opener.open(url)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 211, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 344, in open_http
h.endheaders(data)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 776, in send
self.connect()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 757, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Any clues??

Answer (score 5):

For Windows 7:

1. Right click on `Computer`, and select `Properties`
2. On the left, select `Advanced system settings`
3. Click on the `Advanced` tab, then click `Environment Variables`
4. Click on `New..` under `User Variables`
5. In `Variable name`, type `HTTP_PROXY` and in `Variable value`, type `http://username:password@proxy.com:port` (where `proxy.com` is the hostname or IP address of your proxy, and `port` is the port for it - grab it from Internet Explorer)
6. Click OK, then OK, then OK again to dismiss all the dialog boxes.

Now, when you open a *new* command terminal, Python should be able to access the Internet; and any IDE (once started again), should allow Python to access the Internet.

For Windows XP, when you right click on `My Computer` and select `Properties`, you'll reach the same dialog box where you click on the `Advanced` tab.

Python will read `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` enivronment variables (if set) before it tries to connect to the Internet. If you are using a proxy and these variables are missing, any Python application (unless specifically exempted) cannot access the Internet. So, you won't be able to `pip install` for example - but once you set both of those variables, Python will use the proxy and then will connect to the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for that. it worked! However, the password characters are visible on the python shell when i type it. is there any way i can make the password not visible?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to mask the password; but you shouldn't be typing anything in the Python shell. Simply set the environment variables and then open a new command prompt `cmd.exe` and then without any other configuration from your end, it should work.

Comment: So i am working on Wing IDE. so when i run the commands, it asks me for the username password one after the other. Am i doing sth wrong?

Comment: As I don't use Wing IDE, I cannot comment.